# Creating a new syntax for Sublime text 3

Tags: yaml, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create the syntax highlighting for [Flex](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUuOXZnuHKAhXDNpoKHep-Cs8QFghAMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFlex_(lexical_analyser_generator)&usg=AFQjCNFt5KoQZ6HIa9Av-WU07RNLb6lBHw&sig2=jaQkTfZBvGt37rckwYXLGw). I'm using [PackageDev](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev) and YAML.

So, I want find a blocks, starting with `%{` and ending with `%}`, then I need highlight everything inside this block as C++ code.

I thought about two variants, both of them don't work:

```
# ...
# first
- begin: '%\{'
  end: '%\}'
  contentName:
    patterns:
    - include: source.c++ #  that's doesn't work

# second
- match: '%\{((?:.|\n)*)%\}' # regexpr works correctly
  name: source.c++
  captures:
    '1':
      - include: source.c++ # that's doesn't work too
```

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
- name: markup.italic.lex
  begin: '%\{'
  end: '%\}'
  patterns:
  - include: source.c++
```

Manuals [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) and [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html). Manual for scope names [here](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#naming_conventions).